# In react componentDidUpdate not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to update my state (`start_date`) with the props that coming in to my component, but `setState` is not updating my state. Instead, I am getting a value of `undefined`.

Here's what I am doing in my code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    start_date: ''
  };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log("prevProps ", prevProps)
  console.log("prevState ", prevState)
  if (prevProps.currentRelease != prevState.currentRelease) {
     console.log("Inside componentDidUpdate ")
     this.setState({
    //  start_date: prevProps.currentRelease.start
    });
  }
}
```

and here's a screenshot of my data that's coming in from the parent component passing it down to the child component:

[image: data]

I need to update `start_date` state with **currentRelease.start** (the red box)

Comment: What do you get if you log `prevProps.currentRelease.start`?

Comment: if I console log `prevProps.currentRelease.start` then I can see `8/3/2018` printed out on the console. However, when I use it to update the state then my code is failing.

Comment: why not just use `this.props.currentRelease.start` instead of `this.state.start_date`?

Comment: And you are aware that `console.log` is "lazy" in that it evaluates the value when it displays it, not when you "log" it? So when `console.log` runs the value might be undefined and one second later when it's value is evaluated and printed in the debug console it might be "8/3/2018"?

Comment: is this `console.log("Inside componentDidUpdate ")` being logged?

Comment: yes, it does. I can see that printed out to the console as well.

Comment: Are you trying to say: `if (prevProps.currentRelease.start != prevState.start_date) { ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this. instead of `componentDidupdate`

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const { currentRelease } = props;

    if(currentRelease && currentRelease.start) {
        return { start_date: props.currentRelease.start }
    }

    return null;
}
```

reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Comment: you've forgot to return `null` if `props.currentRelease.start` is missing or is equal to `state. start_date `

Comment: @streletss haha... I mistake this..(static function..) thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, you were updating state with `prevProps` (with old one).

You should use `this.props` (current) props instand of `prevProps`:

**Correct code:**

```
this.setState({
//  start_date: this.props.currentRelease.start
});
```

Your wrong Code :

```
 this.setState({
//  start_date: prevProps.currentRelease.start
});
```

In you code I replaced `prevProps` with `this.props`.